# How to build a javascript array to be converted to JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function that should

1. collect all input data in an array
2. put that array in JSON format (to be used as ajax post data)

Here's what I have, which seems like it should work, but when I log the stringified version, all I get is [].

```
function get_data_from_form() {
    var data = [];
    var inputs = $('form').find('input');

    $.each(inputs, function (index, value) {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');

        data[name] = value; // How should this change?

    });
    console.log('stringified data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); // -> []
}
```

The desired output should be something like: "{ fname: 'turd', lname: 'ferguson' }"

What am I doing wrong? Would it be easier to just make a string and concat the name/value pairs?

Comment: how do you correlate the fields?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You are confusing arrays and objects. Your desired output is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks, I was confusing objects and arrays.

Comment: @TravisHeeter that's actually a trivial problem compared to the issue of extracting the value... :(

Comment: @Alnitak You mean that I'm using the wrong selector: $('form').find(' input')? I actually just used that to simplify things I'm actually using classes, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: No, I meant the use of `this.value` (or jQuerys `$(this).val()` if you must) instead of the `.each(index, value)` you were using.

Comment: OK, I removed the index & value params, and am now using this.name and this.value. Seems to work the same, but the code is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a object, not an array

```
var data = {};

data[name] = value;
```

Comment: Thanks. This and @Alnitak's 'this.value' worked. When I used data[name] = value; it gave me a bunch of metadata. data[name] = this.value worked.

Comment: Oh, it gave me a bunch of metadata for the textarea, targeted with a class, and not input, so maybe that's why I got the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Your `value` extraction field is wrong - in the `.each` call the `value` parameter is the current element, not its value.   Also, you need to capture the fields in a key/value store, i.e. an `Object` instead of an `Array`.  Try this, instead:

```
var data = {};  // NB: *not* an array

$('form :input').each(function() {
    data[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/hsy2xd5L/